# Making densityplot more sensitive in polar coordinate

Tags: plotting

I have used the `DensityPlot` as shown below to show a function

```
Rc = 0.1;

f[r_, t_] := 
  Exp[
    ((Pi/2 + t) (Mod[t + 3 Pi/4, Pi] - Pi/4)^2 + 
        (Pi/2 - t) (Mod[t + Pi/4, Pi] - Pi/4)^2)/
    Log[(r^2 - 2 Rc^2 - r Sqrt[r^2 - 4 Rc^2])/(2 Rc^2)]];

DensityPlot[
  f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 0.8], 
  Exclusions -> Disk[{0, 0}, Rc + 0.1], 
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

But it is not clear in the plot that, the function also depends on $r$ because its value doesn't change clearly as $r$ is increased in the graph. How can I make it more sensitive to $r$ component?

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}`?